# Stucked Java process (jdk 1.8)

Tags: java, strace

I created a simple Java daemon. It's dumb as possible - get some information from database and send it to Samba share

How it looks:

```
while (true) {
   do_some_database_job(connection_pool.getCnx())
   do_some_preprocessing
   Thread.sleep(schedule_interval);
}
```

However, after few iterations it gets stucked.

I inspected JVM process with strace and last record was like this:

```
futex(<a_hex_address>, FUTEX_WAIT, <jvm_pid+some_number>, NULL)
```

So I suspect that it's a deadlock, but why that is? I run only one thread.
I'm using dbcp2 for connection pooling and logback.

Experimented on Win7/RHEL7, jdk1.8/jdk10

Comment: Please create a [MCVE].

Comment: It looks like you're looking at strace or something similar. This is generally too low level to provide helpful information. For Java it would be better to get a [thread dump](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/18178) which will show where your Java application is when you're hanging.

Comment: Are you multitasking or just creating one new thread?

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos I just run on one thread

Comment: Deadlocks are unlikely here, unless you share a variable with the Main-Thread, else you have to add the code of your proccess and preprocess methods